# Using Foundation icon sets via CDN

Tags: node.js, zurb-foundation, cdn, truetype

I am building a NodeJS app and I am using Foundation for my front end.  I want to use the icon sets that Foundation offers but **is it possible to link to a CDN for the icon set rather than use a local copy** of the entire Foundatin framework?

I found a CDN (*//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.ttf*) for the icon set but I have idea how to incorporate this into my app.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need to pull in the CSS file (which will load in the proper font files), then use the classes on elements in your page: `<i class="fi-[icon]"></i>`

[CDNJS foundation-icons.min.css](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.min.css)